# What type of acturator with motor to choice for measurement with step = 0,25 μm?

Tags: measurements, equipment-selection, actuator

I need to select some linear acturator or build it. I see it as:

[image]

On green platform there is pink device. This device must be measured. For this purpose we need to choose linear acturator with carriage (dark blue on picture). Carriage must go along one direction. This carriage must to carry some electrical equipment. Mass of this equipment = 400 g (0,88 lb).

Specification:

[image]

Carriage (other moving element) must have range of motion = 50 mm (2 inch). Minimum motion (step) must equal 0,25 μm (or less). Allowable error of measurement = 7%. We plan to measure 100 points along and only ahead because repeatedly of measurements don't care.

**Question**

1. What types of acturators may be appropriate for this task? What variant is better?

***Additional explanation:***

I have considered two options:

1. Linear acturator on base ball screw rail with carriage and stepper motor. This solution does not satisfy this problem because has low precision.
2. Piezo acturator - useless too, because it has limitation on range of motion (max. 30 mm, when need 50 mm). Moreover piezo acturator very sensitive to
   payload (if that's devices can move 100 g - it's already good).

**Note.**

It's acceptable for my objective if linear acturator will be move platform (green on picture) with electrical equipment. Blue stand with measurement equipment can fixed. In that case payload to platform = 2 kg. And step same = 0,25  μm.

Comment: If the piezo actuator does more than half your stroke, why not just use two in series?

Comment: it's variant I have examined.It has a lot  of lack.
1. How I will be move payload? Piezo variant very weak.
2. Money. nuff said
3. Very time-consuming to write two programs for PC, and add to one. /

Comment: This is an open-ended design and/or shopping question; you've got a set of specifications and expect us (the community) to find the product that meets your needs. The question is probably going to get closed on that basis. That said, if it doesn't, you should post *all* of your specifications. If money is a criteria, then *post it*. I personally think that the ball screw carriage is the way to go, I just wanted to post that you maybe haven't considered all your options.

Comment: With the piezo actuator, are you trying to support the weight of the payload? It looks like you're trying to actuate *side-to-side* and not *up-and-down*, so the weight of the payload doesn't matter, **unless you have a speed/acceleration spec you didn't give.** I don't know why you would need two programs - `if (range<0.5*maxRange) {actuator1 = range; actuator2 = 0} else {actuator1 = 0.5*maxRange; actuator2 = range-0.5*maxRange}`. Easy. If programming is a challenge for you, *add that to your specifications*. If you do need force, use actuators in parallel. You *can* do series/parallel.

Comment: My opinion FWIW, is you will have to use techniques used in the design of coordinate measuring machines. First you have to have the movable platform ride on air bearings so you have no friction. Second you will have to use an analog motor (DC) driving a high gear ratio worm drive so that you need MANY turns of the motor to increment the carriage. A stepping motor will not give you the resolution even if it is the microstepping variety. Third you will need a linear variable displacement transducer as an absolute position encoder in a feedback loop to control the carriage displacement.